# how many worker threads in nodejs?is it possible to modify the number for better performance?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, node.js

As far as I know, nodejs is not single threaded. In the background,a worker threadpool is looping for executing long io tasks that can't finished by epoll etc.
But how many threads in the background? I can't find any documents to grep the number.

If i want nodejs to cooperate with mysql database, there should be several threads to execute long-term query tasks. And it's very dangererous if some of sql queries blocks if there's only a few threads that nodejs provided. So I should be very careful about mysql model definition and sql query performance while it's really some kind of dedicated job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I studied node-mysql recently, and node-mysql is totally event-based using node's eventloop.There's no need to worry about the performance at all.

And node-postgres is the same.

But There is a threadpool in the background.

I studied libeio source and found there's 4 threads in node of old versions.

I studied libuv source and found the number is configurable by process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=number_you_need in node of recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken. node.js is single-threaded.

Most of the good MySQL drivers for node.js are asynchronous, so they do not block the process while waiting for a query to complete.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349276/how-does-node-js-know-if-a-call-has-to-be-executed-in-the-thread-pool-or-in-the?rq=1 deep inside nodejs,there is a threadpool.

Comment: Not within node.js itself, but possibly within certain libraries. But you don't need to concern yourself with them.